# WebAssembly: Import Arg is Not Function

Tags: javascript, web, webassembly

I'm trying out WebAssembly for the first time and was trying to make a program that calls a subtract function in c which calls a add function in JavaScript and gets outputted.

Index.js:

```js
const add = (one, two) => {
    return one + two;
};

const importObject = {
    imports: {
        add,
    },
    env: {
        abort(msg, file, line, column) {
            console.error(`${msg} in ${file} at ${line}:${column}`);
        }
    }
};

const loadWASM = fileName => {
    return fetch(fileName)
        .then(res => res.arrayBuffer())
        .then(buffer => new WebAssembly.Module(buffer))
        .then(module => {
            return new WebAssembly.Instance(module, importObject);
        });
};

loadWASM("./math.wasm").then(module => {
    console.log(module.exports.square(5));
    console.log(module.exports.subtract(7, 5));
});
```

math.c:

```c
int square(int num) {
    return num * num;
}

int subtract(int one, int two) {
    return add(one, -two);
}
```

Error:
Uncaught (in promise) LinkError: import object field 'add' is not a Function